# Is there a reason why iterating with a string works, but iterating with an integer does not?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am writing a function to find the sum of "hole numbers" from range(0, N) (0469 each have one hole, 8 has two holes)

The following function returns a correction answer of 231 when N is 200:

```
def sum_of_holes(N):
    count = 0
    for num in range(1, N + 1):
        num = str(num)
        for i in num:
            if i in ['0', '4', '6', '9']:
                count += 1
            if i == '8':
                count += 2
    return count
```

However the following function returns an incorrect answer of 6 when N is 200 (and always returns 6 when N > 10):

```
def sum_of_holes2(N):
    count = 0
    for num in range(N+1):
        if num in [0, 4, 6, 9]:
            count += 1
        elif num == 8:
            count += 2
    return count
```

Comment: well naturally, because you are testing the digits for holes, not the entire range of numbers from 0 to N right?

Comment: "hole numbers?" do you mean "whole numbers?"

Comment: @Xenolion (visually) he's talking about 0 having one enclosed space, 4 having one enclosed space, 8 having two enclosed spaces, etc..

Comment: @user120242 I am testing the entire range of numbers from 0 to N

Comment: @Xenolion sorry I do mean "hole numbers", please refer to user120242's comment for a better description

Comment: @pizza123 right, but when you test 200, you are testing "2" "0" "0", not "200"

Comment: I have got it now

Comment: The second algorythm tests all numbers from 0 to 200  and only the numbers 0,4,6,8,9 will add anything to count. The first one tests the digits of each number, so `146` will test 1 (does not add anything) 4 (adds 1) and 6 (adds 1) - the first algo does NOT check 146 at all because it is neither of [0,2,4,6,8,9]

Comment: Is 200 one of 0, 4, 6, 9?  No, so it returns false.  A string is different, each character can be iterated over.  so for x in "asdf":  will iterate over x = "a", "s", "d", "f"

Comment: @PatrickArtner I see!!!!! Thank you!!

Comment: And thank you @user120242 for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def sum_of_holes2(N):
    count = 0
    for num in range(N+1):
        if num in [0, 4, 6, 9]:
            count += 1
        elif num == 8:
            count += 2
    return count
```

You're testing if num is equal to either 0, 4, 6, 9, then add 1 else if num is equal to 8 then add 2. If i understand correctly, you're trying to count the holes on each digit of num, hence your `for i in num` loop in your first function (your `i` being a digit of your num). The second function is incorrect (if num > 10, say for instance 200, you're testing if  200 is either 0 4 6 8 or 9, since it's none of those, count does not increment).

The reason why you always obtain 6 when N>10 is because if you loop to N > 10, your num will be equal at a moment to 0 4 6 8 9, setting your count to 6 ( +1 * 4 +2 * 1).

Hope it's clear.

Comment: I see now! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
if num in [0, 4, 6, 9]:
```

This code checks whether the *entire* input number is in the array [0, 4, 6, 9]. So, the condition will only be True when num == 0, num == 4, num == 6, num == 9 (it cannot be true if num is greater than 9).

On the other hand, this code

```
    num = str(num)
    for i in num:
```

checks num *digit by digit*. The for loop iterates over the characters in the string (which are the digits of the number) and checks if the digit is equal to any of the characters (digits) in the array. Note that the array `['0', '4', '6', '9']` must contain strings because the type of i is a string.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like I had overlooked something so simple..